# Is it possible to scan for any transmitting wireless device, even unconnected ones?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I try to make use of broken wifi printer I had lying around an my basement for a while. The mechanics is broken, so that the printer is stuck with an error and don't let me configure the wireless interface any more. Is it technically possible to scan to what access point it wants to connect to? When I know the ssid, I can possibly remember the password.
What tools can I use to do this on Kubuntu linux?

Comment: Most wireless printers have the capability to print their current configuration

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to sniff wireless packets with a PC, so you can see which SSID your printer tries to connect do (if it does an active scan at all, instead of simply waiting for the beacon of the SSID it wants).

The `aircrack-ng` package (available in Debian, therefore probably in Kubuntu, too) contains tools for this: `airmon-ng` is a script to switch your wlan interface to monitor mode, and `airodump-ng` will react to SSID scans and display the corresponding SSID.

You can also use `iw` to [enable monitor mode manually](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121215/how-to-enable-wifi-while-using-two-wireless-cards-one-in-monitor-mode-and-other), and `wireshark` to capture all packets.

There are probably other tools for this, too.